# Solve Ax = b, A = lower triangular matrix in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, linear-algebra, equation-solving

I`m trying to do this function that solves linear systems, A*x = b, where A =  lower triangular matrix, linear independent matrix and with only one solution.
But the results always show 0 0 0 0 ...
I have printed the sum, s, and it always shows 0 as well...

```
 #include  <iostream>
 using namespace std;

void solve(int n, float a[][MAX], float b[], float x[]){
 int i,j;
 float s;

 for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        s = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){

            s = s + a[i][j]*x[j];
            cout<<s<<endl;
        }
    x[i] = (b[i] - s)/a[i][i];
 }
}
```

Comment: can't you use lapack?

Comment: no, it has to be in c++, with "simple libraries and packs"...

Comment: This is a famous algorithm. It's called back substitution. Try google for a bit. I'm quite sure you will find it step by step :) If you're still stuck scream for help.

Comment: @LVL can we use upper triangular matrix?

Comment: back substitution isn`t working :(. But yes, @lizusek, we can use a upper triangular

Comment: @LVL what do you mean, what is not working? do you refer to my answer or someone else or back substitution algorithm?

Comment: the back substitution algorithm

Comment: @LVL it is working, really. Have you tried my version posted below? Note the range of sumation

Comment: Now i see... It`s working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void solve(int n, float a[][MAX], float b[], float x[]){
  int i,j;
  float s;

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        s = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                       ^
            s = s + a[ i][ j] * x[ j];
        }
        x[ i] = ( b[ i] - s) / a[ i][ i];
   }
}
```

[BackSubstitution.pdf](http://ktuce.ktu.edu.tr/~pehlivan/numerical_analysis/chap02/BackSubstitution.pdf)

[compiled example](http://ideone.com/3p3N04)

Comment: the compiled example does not work (=not robust) for certain input. For instance, I enter $a[3][3]={0.2,-0.2,0,0,0.3,-0.2,0,0,0.25}$ and $b[3]={3,3,3}$. The codes compiles but leads to an incorrect answer as 15,10,12. Is it a way to fix the codes?

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
```

Should be:

```
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
```

Then it works fine - assuming your pivots are always non zero.

Comment: @lizusek Err... no? For instance when i=1 s should be A[1][0]*x[0] while in your code is simply 0. You have to sum all the A[i][j]*x[j] **on the left** of the diagonal, so basically for i < j.